# DomDocument and cURL not returning updated values

Tags: php, html, curl, domdocument

PHP Script

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_all);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);


 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.gloryfeed.com/scale405.html');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

 $output = curl_exec($ch);

 if($output == FALSE){
   echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
 }

 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML( $output );
 $test = $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementById('displayedWeight'));

 //$dom->getElementById('displayedWeight')

 curl_close($ch);

 echo "Your 'Weight' is: " . $test . "\n";

 //print_r($output);
?>
```

HTML PAGE

```
<div class="weightDisplay" id="displayedWeight">0</div>
```

That is the variable I am trying to get. The page has an update function that updates the div weightDisplayed. However when curl grabs the page and DomDocument parses the data is it just receiving the default value of 0. Is there any way to grab the updated value?

Comment: Looks like it is being updated with ajax you need to use that url. This is what the ajex was grabbing http://www.gloryfeed.com/get_var.cgi?index=99

Comment: Thank you very much! does DomDocument have a function to parse a certain about of characters out? what im getting "{"title":"Web","type":2,"value":"0|0|0|0|1|0|4840|lb|Gross"}"
what i want "4840|lb|Gross"

Comment: No that is not the problem. The value is being updated with javascript. curl does not run javascript. So all you can do is grab the default value.

Comment: Im saying if i save that value into a string with PHP, or an html page with DomDocument, is there a function to admit the first certian number of characters?

Comment: DomDocument is not what you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the information into a array;

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_all);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.gloryfeed.com/get_var.cgi?index=99');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if($output == FALSE){
  echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}

$test = json_decode($output,true);
print_r($test);
echo('<br>');
$test = explode('|',$test['value']);
print_r($test);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Don't meant to be a code vampire, but im very new to all this. Once it was in the array, i just pulled out the varribles i needed and we are good to go.